# Using Object.keys with array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the following object

```
var obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

is it possible, using `Object.keys` (no loop), to get key (low/medium/high) by one of the corresponding values?

Comment: No, there's no direct way to look up an entry by its value.  You'd have to loop over the keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "no loop"? You have to use a loop of some sort for this, whether that is an explicit loop like `for`, or one abstracted away in a method such as `.find()`

Comment: I mean no ```for``` loop, exactly.

Comment: If your goal is to find values quickly and/or conveniently, you'd have to pre-process the object to create something like `var objMap = {1: "low", 2: "low", 3: "low", 4: "medium" ...};`

Comment: I'm looking for a more concise solution - if possible.

Comment: Solution to what?  The answer to your posted question is simply "no".  If you have a broader goal in mind, you should edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]};


function getKey(n) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].includes(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would really like to avoid `for loop`, you can use `Array#reduce` instead.

```js
var obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]};

const fn = (value, arr) => 
   Object.entries(arr)
     .reduce((s, [key, a]) => (a.indexOf(value) > -1 ? key : s), null);

console.log(fn(7, obj));
console.log(fn(1, obj));
```

Comment: This works but it will allways iterate over all properties even if the first is the solution. That's why I use `findIndex`and `some`.

Comment: @Sascha It really depends on requirements - if the values may include duplicates and the last condition-fulfilling key has to be returned - this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [Array#findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]};

function mySearch(obj,search) {
    return Object.keys(obj)[(Object.values(obj).findIndex(el => el.some(val => val===search)))];
}

console.log(mySearch(obj, 5));
console.log(mySearch(obj, 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to return the key according to the value passed.
the function uses Object.keys and Array.find()

```
var obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]};

const findKeyByValue = (value)=>{
 return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].find(element => element === value))
}

console.log(findKeyByValue(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this without a custom approach, there are a lot of ways for accomplishing what you want.

This approach uses the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object to find the key by the accessed property and keeps the entries to be able to provide quick access.

```js
const obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]},
      decorate = (o) => {
        const entries = Object.entries(o);
        return new Proxy(o, {
            get(_, accessedProperty) {
              let [key] = (entries.find(([_, values]) => values.includes(+accessedProperty)) || []);
              return key;
            }
        });
      },
      decoratedObj = decorate(obj);


console.log(decoratedObj[1]);
console.log(decoratedObj[4]);
console.log(decoratedObj[10]);
console.log(decoratedObj[11]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a different data structure than a basic object. Have a look at the [bidirectional map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map). This is a data strucure that allows you to look up values by their key, and keys by their value.

I can recommend [this implementation](https://yomguithereal.github.io/mnemonist/bi-map). It's part of [mnemonist](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/mnemonist), which has a bunch of handy data structures for different use cases!

```
import BiMap from 'mnemonist/bi-map';

const obj = {'low': [1, 2, 3], 'medium': [4, 5, 6], 'high': [7, 8, 9, 10]};

const lookupTable = BiMap.from(obj);

console.log(lookupTable.get('low'))
// > [1,2,3]

console.log(lookupTable.inverse.get([1,2,3]))
// > 'low'
```

Comment: I've never used the code snippet feature before, I couldn't figure out how to add my dependency correctly. I have a link to the library in my answer. If you know how to add the dependency to the snippet, please feel free to edit. I would be very appreciative!